# Download files from server returns Invalid CSRF Token

Tags: angular, spring

I'm trying to download files from specific folders based on the passed ID.

I have written the code with spring where it takes the uuid to download that specific file, then call that route on Angular

On the frontend:

```js
  download(id) {
    return this.api.getBackendUrl() + '/' + this.app.plantUUID + '/projects/' + this.myView.projectID + '/FILE/' + id + '/download';
  };
```

Backend:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{plantUUID}/projects/{projectUUID}/FILE")

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{uuid}/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String uuid, ServletWebRequest request) {
        UxFile file = fileService.findByUUID(uuid);

        return genericFileController.download(file, request, new HttpHeaders());
    }
```

Now when going to a url like this:
`http://localhost:1113/api/v1/7f45c1b1-b0c4-4f2d-96fd-a786889fbae2/projects/2723ec7d-3d2b-41f3-b332-b2e384a8e03a/FILE/5ddf096d-f49a-479b-8f8d-5ae10312a435/download`

I get `Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.`
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bISa.png)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter with Angular. The error should returned from your backend security checking. You are required to include the CSRF token into your client side request.

Here is [some document](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf) for it.

Comment: Do you mean I should send the CSRF token from Angular to the backend ?